# AES Encryption: [1][1] and [1][2] in Round 1, [1][1] in Round 2 erronous, the rest is correct

Tags: encryption, aes

I am trying to implement an AES cipher according to this specification:
http://techheap.packetizer.com/cryptography/encryption/spec.v36.pdf

According to the example (page 20 onwards) my results for the state after MixColumns for Rounds 1 and 2 are erronous:

Round 1 after MixColumns

```
example state   my state
04 e0 48 28     04 e0 48 28
66 cb f8 06     66 60 f8 06<
81 19 d3 26     81 28 d3 26<
e5 9a 7a 4c     e5 9a 7a 4c
                   ^^
```

If i then correct the two different bytes and go on to calculate Round 2 `[1][1]` is still incorrect whereas `[1][2]` is correct:

```
example state   my state
58 1b db 1b     58 1b db 1b
4d 4b e7 6b     4d 17 e7 6b<
ca 5a ca b0     ca 5a ca b0
f1 ac a8 e5     f1 ac a8 e5
                   ^^
```

If i then again correct `[1][1]` and continue calculating my state after MixColumns for Round 3 is identical to the example.

These are the mix-column values for `[1][1]` `[1][2]` in  Round 1:

```
FFmul(2, t[1] = b4) = d8
FFmul(3, t[(1 + 1) % 4] = t[2] = 52) = f6
t[(1 + 2) % 4] = t[3] = ae
t[(1 + 3) % 4] = t[0] = e0
=> 60

FFmul(2, t[2] = 52) = 95
FFmul(3, t[(2 + 1) % 4] = t[3] = ae) = e9
t[(2 + 2) % 4] = t[0] = e0
t[(2 + 3) % 4] = t[1] = b4
=> 28
```

and here the mix-column values for `[1][1]` in Round 3:

```
FFmul(2, t[1] = 39) = 2e
FFmul(3, t[(1 + 1) % 4] = t[2] = 53) = f5
t[(1 + 2) % 4] = t[3] = 89
t[(1 + 3) % 4] = t[0] = 45
```

I am probably just not seeing the obvious reason, this is the sourcecode (key expansion is not yet implented therefore the round-keys are hardcoded):

```
public class Tester
{

    public static final byte[][] logTable = new byte[][] {  
        {(byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x19, (byte) 0x01, (byte) 0x32, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x1a, (byte) 0xc6,
         (byte) 0x4b, (byte) 0xc7, (byte) 0x1b, (byte) 0x68, (byte) 0x33, (byte) 0xee, (byte) 0xdf, (byte) 0x03},
        {(byte) 0x64, (byte) 0x04, (byte) 0xe0, (byte) 0x0e, (byte) 0x34, (byte) 0x8d, (byte) 0x81, (byte) 0xef,
         (byte) 0x4c, (byte) 0x71, (byte) 0x08, (byte) 0xc8, (byte) 0xf8, (byte) 0x69, (byte) 0x1c, (byte) 0xc1},
        {(byte) 0x7d, (byte) 0xc2, (byte) 0x1d, (byte) 0xb5, (byte) 0xf9, (byte) 0xb9, (byte) 0x27, (byte) 0x6a,
         (byte) 0x4d, (byte) 0xe4, (byte) 0xa6, (byte) 0x72, (byte) 0x9a, (byte) 0xc9, (byte) 0x09, (byte) 0x78},
        {(byte) 0x65, (byte) 0x2f, (byte) 0x8a, (byte) 0x05, (byte) 0x21, (byte) 0x0f, (byte) 0xe1, (byte) 0x24,
         (byte) 0x12, (byte) 0xf0, (byte) 0x82, (byte) 0x45, (byte) 0x35, (byte) 0x93, (byte) 0xda, (byte) 0x8e},
        {(byte) 0x96, (byte) 0x8f, (byte) 0xdb, (byte) 0xbd, (byte) 0x36, (byte) 0xd0, (byte) 0xce, (byte) 0x94,
         (byte) 0x13, (byte) 0x5c, (byte) 0xd2, (byte) 0xf1, (byte) 0x40, (byte) 0x46, (byte) 0x83, (byte) 0x38},
        {(byte) 0x66, (byte) 0xdd, (byte) 0xfd, (byte) 0x30, (byte) 0xbf, (byte) 0x06, (byte) 0x8b, (byte) 0x62,
         (byte) 0xb3, (byte) 0x25, (byte) 0xe2, (byte) 0x98, (byte) 0x22, (byte) 0x88, (byte) 0x91, (byte) 0x10},
        {(byte) 0x7e, (byte) 0x6e, (byte) 0x48, (byte) 0xc3, (byte) 0xa3, (byte) 0xb6, (byte) 0x1e, (byte) 0x42,
         (byte) 0x3a, (byte) 0x6b, (byte) 0x28, (byte) 0x54, (byte) 0xfa, (byte) 0x85, (byte) 0x3d, (byte) 0xba},
        {(byte) 0x2b, (byte) 0x79, (byte) 0x0a, (byte) 0x15, (byte) 0x9b, (byte) 0x9f, (byte) 0x5e, (byte) 0xca,
         (byte) 0x4e, (byte) 0xd4, (byte) 0xac, (byte) 0xe5, (byte) 0xf3, (byte) 0x73, (byte) 0xa7, (byte) 0x57},
        {(byte) 0xaf, (byte) 0x58, (byte) 0xa8, (byte) 0x50, (byte) 0xf4, (byte) 0xea, (byte) 0xd6, (byte) 0x74,
         (byte) 0x4f, (byte) 0xae, (byte) 0xe9, (byte) 0xd5, (byte) 0xe7, (byte) 0xe6, (byte) 0xad, (byte) 0xe8},
        {(byte) 0x2c, (byte) 0xd7, (byte) 0x75, (byte) 0x7a, (byte) 0xeb, (byte) 0x16, (byte) 0x0b, (byte) 0xf5,
         (byte) 0x59, (byte) 0xcb, (byte) 0x5f, (byte) 0xb0, (byte) 0x9c, (byte) 0xa9, (byte) 0x51, (byte) 0xa0},
        {(byte) 0x7f, (byte) 0x0c, (byte) 0xf6, (byte) 0x6f, (byte) 0x17, (byte) 0xc4, (byte) 0x49, (byte) 0xec,
         (byte) 0xd8, (byte) 0x43, (byte) 0x1f, (byte) 0x2d, (byte) 0xa4, (byte) 0x76, (byte) 0x7b, (byte) 0xb7},
        {(byte) 0xcc, (byte) 0xbb, (byte) 0x3e, (byte) 0x5a, (byte) 0xfb, (byte) 0x60, (byte) 0xb1, (byte) 0x86,
         (byte) 0x3b, (byte) 0x52, (byte) 0xa1, (byte) 0x6c, (byte) 0xaa, (byte) 0x55, (byte) 0x29, (byte) 0x9d},
        {(byte) 0x97, (byte) 0xb2, (byte) 0x87, (byte) 0x90, (byte) 0x61, (byte) 0xbe, (byte) 0xdc, (byte) 0xfc,
         (byte) 0xbc, (byte) 0x95, (byte) 0xcf, (byte) 0xcd, (byte) 0x37, (byte) 0x3f, (byte) 0x5b, (byte) 0xd1},
        {(byte) 0x53, (byte) 0x39, (byte) 0x84, (byte) 0x3c, (byte) 0x41, (byte) 0xa2, (byte) 0x6d, (byte) 0x47,
         (byte) 0x14, (byte) 0x2a, (byte) 0x9e, (byte) 0x5d, (byte) 0x56, (byte) 0xf2, (byte) 0xd3, (byte) 0xab},
        {(byte) 0x44, (byte) 0x11, (byte) 0x92, (byte) 0xd9, (byte) 0x23, (byte) 0x20, (byte) 0x2e, (byte) 0x89,
         (byte) 0xb4, (byte) 0x7c, (byte) 0xb8, (byte) 0x26, (byte) 0x77, (byte) 0x99, (byte) 0xe3, (byte) 0xa5},
        {(byte) 0x67, (byte) 0x4a, (byte) 0xed, (byte) 0xde, (byte) 0xc5, (byte) 0x31, (byte) 0xfe, (byte) 0x18,
         (byte) 0x0d, (byte) 0x63, (byte) 0x8c, (byte) 0x80, (byte) 0xc0, (byte) 0xf7, (byte) 0x70, (byte) 0x07}
    };

    public static final byte[][] powTable = new byte[][] {
        {(byte) 0x01, (byte) 0x03, (byte) 0x05, (byte) 0x0f, (byte) 0x11, (byte) 0x33, (byte) 0x55, (byte) 0xff,
         (byte) 0x1a, (byte) 0x2e, (byte) 0x72, (byte) 0x96, (byte) 0xa1, (byte) 0xf8, (byte) 0x13, (byte) 0x35},
        {(byte) 0x5f, (byte) 0xe1, (byte) 0x38, (byte) 0x48, (byte) 0xd8, (byte) 0x73, (byte) 0x95, (byte) 0xa4,
         (byte) 0xf7, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x06, (byte) 0x0a, (byte) 0x1e, (byte) 0x22, (byte) 0x66, (byte) 0xaa},
        {(byte) 0xe5, (byte) 0x34, (byte) 0x5c, (byte) 0xe4, (byte) 0x37, (byte) 0x59, (byte) 0xeb, (byte) 0x26,
         (byte) 0x6a, (byte) 0xbe, (byte) 0xd9, (byte) 0x70, (byte) 0x90, (byte) 0xab, (byte) 0xe6, (byte) 0x31},
        {(byte) 0x53, (byte) 0xf5, (byte) 0x04, (byte) 0x0c, (byte) 0x14, (byte) 0x3c, (byte) 0x44, (byte) 0xcc,
         (byte) 0x4f, (byte) 0xd1, (byte) 0x68, (byte) 0xb8, (byte) 0xd3, (byte) 0x6e, (byte) 0xb2, (byte) 0xcd},
        {(byte) 0x4c, (byte) 0xd4, (byte) 0x67, (byte) 0xa9, (byte) 0xe0, (byte) 0x3b, (byte) 0x4d, (byte) 0xd7,
         (byte) 0x62, (byte) 0xa6, (byte) 0xf1, (byte) 0x08, (byte) 0x18, (byte) 0x28, (byte) 0x78, (byte) 0x88},
        {(byte) 0x83, (byte) 0x9e, (byte) 0xb9, (byte) 0xd0, (byte) 0x6b, (byte) 0xbd, (byte) 0xdc, (byte) 0x7f,
         (byte) 0x81, (byte) 0x98, (byte) 0xb3, (byte) 0xce, (byte) 0x49, (byte) 0xdb, (byte) 0x76, (byte) 0x9a},
        {(byte) 0xb5, (byte) 0xc4, (byte) 0x57, (byte) 0xf9, (byte) 0x10, (byte) 0x30, (byte) 0x50, (byte) 0xf0,
         (byte) 0x0b, (byte) 0x1d, (byte) 0x27, (byte) 0x69, (byte) 0xbb, (byte) 0xd6, (byte) 0x61, (byte) 0xa3},
        {(byte) 0xfe, (byte) 0x19, (byte) 0x2b, (byte) 0x7d, (byte) 0x87, (byte) 0x92, (byte) 0xad, (byte) 0xec,
         (byte) 0x2f, (byte) 0x71, (byte) 0x93, (byte) 0xae, (byte) 0xe9, (byte) 0x20, (byte) 0x60, (byte) 0xa0},
        {(byte) 0xfb, (byte) 0x16, (byte) 0x3a, (byte) 0x4e, (byte) 0xd2, (byte) 0x6d, (byte) 0xb7, (byte) 0xc2,
         (byte) 0x5d, (byte) 0xe7, (byte) 0x32, (byte) 0x56, (byte) 0xfa, (byte) 0x15, (byte) 0x3f, (byte) 0x41},
        {(byte) 0xc3, (byte) 0x5e, (byte) 0xe2, (byte) 0x3d, (byte) 0x47, (byte) 0xc9, (byte) 0x40, (byte) 0xc0,
         (byte) 0x5b, (byte) 0xed, (byte) 0x2c, (byte) 0x74, (byte) 0x9c, (byte) 0xbf, (byte) 0xda, (byte) 0x75},
        {(byte) 0x9f, (byte) 0xba, (byte) 0xd5, (byte) 0x64, (byte) 0xac, (byte) 0xef, (byte) 0x2a, (byte) 0x7e,
         (byte) 0x82, (byte) 0x9d, (byte) 0xbc, (byte) 0xdf, (byte) 0x7a, (byte) 0x8e, (byte) 0x89, (byte) 0x80},
        {(byte) 0x9b, (byte) 0xb6, (byte) 0xc1, (byte) 0x58, (byte) 0xe8, (byte) 0x23, (byte) 0x65, (byte) 0xaf,
         (byte) 0xea, (byte) 0x25, (byte) 0x6f, (byte) 0xb1, (byte) 0xc8, (byte) 0x43, (byte) 0xc5, (byte) 0x54},
        {(byte) 0xfc, (byte) 0x1f, (byte) 0x21, (byte) 0x63, (byte) 0xa5, (byte) 0xf4, (byte) 0x07, (byte) 0x09,
         (byte) 0x1b, (byte) 0x2d, (byte) 0x77, (byte) 0x99, (byte) 0xb0, (byte) 0xcb, (byte) 0x46, (byte) 0xca},
        {(byte) 0x45, (byte) 0xcf, (byte) 0x4a, (byte) 0xde, (byte) 0x79, (byte) 0x8b, (byte) 0x86, (byte) 0x91,
         (byte) 0xa8, (byte) 0xe3, (byte) 0x3e, (byte) 0x42, (byte) 0xc6, (byte) 0x51, (byte) 0xf3, (byte) 0x0e},
        {(byte) 0x12, (byte) 0x36, (byte) 0x5a, (byte) 0xee, (byte) 0x29, (byte) 0x7b, (byte) 0x8d, (byte) 0x8c,
         (byte) 0x8f, (byte) 0x8a, (byte) 0x85, (byte) 0x94, (byte) 0xa7, (byte) 0xf2, (byte) 0x0d, (byte) 0x17},
        {(byte) 0x39, (byte) 0x4b, (byte) 0xdd, (byte) 0x7c, (byte) 0x84, (byte) 0x97, (byte) 0xa2, (byte) 0xfd,
         (byte) 0x1c, (byte) 0x24, (byte) 0x6c, (byte) 0xb4, (byte) 0xc7, (byte) 0x52, (byte) 0xf6, (byte) 0x01}  
    };

    public static final byte[][] substitutionTable = new byte[][] {
        {(byte) 0x63, (byte) 0x7c, (byte) 0x77, (byte) 0x7b, (byte) 0xf2, (byte) 0x6b, (byte) 0x6f, (byte) 0xc5,
         (byte) 0x30, (byte) 0x01, (byte) 0x67, (byte) 0x2b, (byte) 0xfe, (byte) 0xd7, (byte) 0xab, (byte) 0x76},
        {(byte) 0xca, (byte) 0x82, (byte) 0xc9, (byte) 0x7d, (byte) 0xfa, (byte) 0x59, (byte) 0x47, (byte) 0xf0,
         (byte) 0xad, (byte) 0xd4, (byte) 0xa2, (byte) 0xaf, (byte) 0x9c, (byte) 0xa4, (byte) 0x72, (byte) 0xc0},
        {(byte) 0xb7, (byte) 0xfd, (byte) 0x93, (byte) 0x26, (byte) 0x36, (byte) 0x3f, (byte) 0xf7, (byte) 0xcc,
         (byte) 0x34, (byte) 0xa5, (byte) 0xe5, (byte) 0xf1, (byte) 0x71, (byte) 0xd8, (byte) 0x31, (byte) 0x15},
        {(byte) 0x04, (byte) 0xc7, (byte) 0x23, (byte) 0xc3, (byte) 0x18, (byte) 0x96, (byte) 0x05, (byte) 0x9a,
         (byte) 0x07, (byte) 0x12, (byte) 0x80, (byte) 0xe2, (byte) 0xeb, (byte) 0x27, (byte) 0xb2, (byte) 0x75},
        {(byte) 0x09, (byte) 0x83, (byte) 0x2c, (byte) 0x1a, (byte) 0x1b, (byte) 0x6e, (byte) 0x5a, (byte) 0xa0,
         (byte) 0x52, (byte) 0x3b, (byte) 0xd6, (byte) 0xb3, (byte) 0x29, (byte) 0xe3, (byte) 0x2f, (byte) 0x84},
        {(byte) 0x53, (byte) 0xd1, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0xed, (byte) 0x20, (byte) 0xfc, (byte) 0xb1, (byte) 0x5b,
         (byte) 0x6a, (byte) 0xcb, (byte) 0xbe, (byte) 0x39, (byte) 0x4a, (byte) 0x4c, (byte) 0x58, (byte) 0xcf},
        {(byte) 0xd0, (byte) 0xef, (byte) 0xaa, (byte) 0xfb, (byte) 0x43, (byte) 0x4d, (byte) 0x33, (byte) 0x85,
         (byte) 0x45, (byte) 0xf9, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x7f, (byte) 0x50, (byte) 0x3c, (byte) 0x9f, (byte) 0xa8},
        {(byte) 0x51, (byte) 0xa3, (byte) 0x40, (byte) 0x8f, (byte) 0x92, (byte) 0x9d, (byte) 0x38, (byte) 0xf5,
         (byte) 0xbc, (byte) 0xb6, (byte) 0xda, (byte) 0x21, (byte) 0x10, (byte) 0xff, (byte) 0xf3, (byte) 0xd2},
        {(byte) 0xcd, (byte) 0x0c, (byte) 0x13, (byte) 0xec, (byte) 0x5f, (byte) 0x97, (byte) 0x44, (byte) 0x17,
         (byte) 0xc4, (byte) 0xa7, (byte) 0x7e, (byte) 0x3d, (byte) 0x64, (byte) 0x5d, (byte) 0x19, (byte) 0x73},
        {(byte) 0x60, (byte) 0x81, (byte) 0x4f, (byte) 0xdc, (byte) 0x22, (byte) 0x2a, (byte) 0x90, (byte) 0x88,
         (byte) 0x46, (byte) 0xee, (byte) 0xb8, (byte) 0x14, (byte) 0xde, (byte) 0x5e, (byte) 0x0b, (byte) 0xdb},
        {(byte) 0xe0, (byte) 0x32, (byte) 0x3a, (byte) 0x0a, (byte) 0x49, (byte) 0x06, (byte) 0x24, (byte) 0x5c,
         (byte) 0xc2, (byte) 0xd3, (byte) 0xac, (byte) 0x62, (byte) 0x91, (byte) 0x95, (byte) 0xe4, (byte) 0x79},
        {(byte) 0xe7, (byte) 0xc8, (byte) 0x37, (byte) 0x6d, (byte) 0x8d, (byte) 0xd5, (byte) 0x4e, (byte) 0xa9,
         (byte) 0x6c, (byte) 0x56, (byte) 0xf4, (byte) 0xea, (byte) 0x65, (byte) 0x7a, (byte) 0xae, (byte) 0x08},
        {(byte) 0xba, (byte) 0x78, (byte) 0x25, (byte) 0x2e, (byte) 0x1c, (byte) 0xa6, (byte) 0xb4, (byte) 0xc6,
         (byte) 0xe8, (byte) 0xdd, (byte) 0x74, (byte) 0x1f, (byte) 0x4b, (byte) 0xbd, (byte) 0x8b, (byte) 0x8a},
        {(byte) 0x70, (byte) 0x3e, (byte) 0xb5, (byte) 0x66, (byte) 0x48, (byte) 0x03, (byte) 0xf6, (byte) 0x0e,
         (byte) 0x61, (byte) 0x35, (byte) 0x57, (byte) 0xb9, (byte) 0x86, (byte) 0xc1, (byte) 0x1d, (byte) 0x9e},
        {(byte) 0xe1, (byte) 0xf8, (byte) 0x98, (byte) 0x11, (byte) 0x69, (byte) 0xd9, (byte) 0x8e, (byte) 0x94,
         (byte) 0x9b, (byte) 0x1e, (byte) 0x87, (byte) 0xe9, (byte) 0xce, (byte) 0x55, (byte) 0x28, (byte) 0xdf},
        {(byte) 0x8c, (byte) 0xa1, (byte) 0x89, (byte) 0x0d, (byte) 0xbf, (byte) 0xe6, (byte) 0x42, (byte) 0x68,
         (byte) 0x41, (byte) 0x99, (byte) 0x2d, (byte) 0x0f, (byte) 0xb0, (byte) 0x54, (byte) 0xbb, (byte) 0x16}
    };

    public static void main(String... args) throws Exception
    {
        byte[] input = new byte[] {
            (byte) 0x32, (byte) 0x43, (byte) 0xf6, (byte) 0xa8, (byte) 0x88, (byte) 0x5a, (byte) 0x30, (byte) 0x8d,
            (byte) 0x31, (byte) 0x31, (byte) 0x98, (byte) 0xa2, (byte) 0xe0, (byte) 0x37, (byte) 0x07, (byte) 0x34
        };
        byte[] key = new byte[] {
            (byte) 0x2b, (byte) 0x7e, (byte) 0x15, (byte) 0x16, (byte) 0x28, (byte) 0xae, (byte) 0xd2, (byte) 0xa6,
            (byte) 0xab, (byte) 0xf7, (byte) 0x15, (byte) 0x88, (byte) 0x09, (byte) 0xcf, (byte) 0x4f, (byte) 0x3c
        };

        byte[] roundKey1 = new byte[] {
            (byte) 0xa0, (byte) 0xfa, (byte) 0xfe, (byte) 0x17, (byte) 0x88, (byte) 0x54, (byte) 0x2c, (byte) 0xb1,
            (byte) 0x23, (byte) 0xa3, (byte) 0x39, (byte) 0x39, (byte) 0x2a, (byte) 0x6c, (byte) 0x76, (byte) 0x05
        };

        byte[] roundKey2 = new byte[] {
            (byte) 0xf2, (byte) 0xc2, (byte) 0x95, (byte) 0xf2, (byte) 0x7a, (byte) 0x96, (byte) 0xb9, (byte) 0x43,
            (byte) 0x59, (byte) 0x35, (byte) 0x80, (byte) 0x7a, (byte) 0x73, (byte) 0x59, (byte) 0xf6, (byte) 0x7f
        };

        // [row][col]
        byte[][] state = new byte[4][4];

        // [round][row][col]
        byte[][][] roundKeys = new byte[3][4][4];

        // [row]
        byte[] shiftRowsOffsets = new byte[] {0, 1, 2, 3};

        // fill the arrays
        fillTable(state, input);
        fillTable(roundKeys[0], key);
        fillTable(roundKeys[1], roundKey1);
        fillTable(roundKeys[2], roundKey2);

        // printTable(state);
        // printTable(roundKeys[0]);

        tableXOR(state, roundKeys[0]);
        //printTable(state);

        substituteBytes(state);
        // printTable(state);

        shiftRows(state, shiftRowsOffsets);
        // printTable(state);

        mixColumns(state);
        printTable(state);

        state[1][1] = (byte) 0xcb;
        state[2][1] = (byte) 0x19;

        tableXOR(state, roundKeys[1]);

        substituteBytes(state);
        shiftRows(state, shiftRowsOffsets);

        mixColumns(state);
        printTable(state);
        state[1][1] = (byte) 0x4b;

        tableXOR(state, roundKeys[2]);
        substituteBytes(state);
        shiftRows(state, shiftRowsOffsets);
        mixColumns(state);

        printTable(state);
    }

    public static void printTable(byte[][] table)
    {
        synchronized(System.out)
        {
            System.out.print("   ");
            for (byte col = 0;col < table[0].length;col++)
            {
                System.out.print(formatHex(col, ' '));
                System.out.print(' ');
            }
            System.out.println();
            for (byte row = 0;row < table.length;row++)
            {
                System.out.print(formatHex(row, ' '));
                System.out.print(' ');
                for (byte col = 0;col < table[row].length;col++)
                {
                    System.out.print(formatHex(table[row][col], '0'));
                    System.out.print(' ');
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
    }

    public static String formatHex(byte value, char pad)
    {
        int val = value & 0xFF;
        String str = Integer.toString(val, 16);
        if (str.length() == 2)
        {
            return str;
        }
        else
        {
            return pad + str;
        }
    }

    public static void substituteBytes(byte[][] target)
    {
        for (int row = 0;row < 4;row++)
        {
            for (int col = 0;col < target[row].length;col++)
            {
                target[row][col] = lookupTable(substitutionTable, target[row][col]);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void tableXOR(byte[][] dataTarget, byte[][] xorSource)
    {
        for (int row = 0;row < dataTarget.length;row++)
        {
            for (int col = 0;col < dataTarget[row].length;col++)
            {
                dataTarget[row][col] = (byte) (dataTarget[row][col] ^ xorSource[row][col]);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void fillTable(byte[][] table, byte[] data)
    {
        int pointer = 0;
        for (int col = 0;col < table[0].length;col++)
        {
            for (int row = 0;row < table.length;row++)
            {
                table[row][col] = data[pointer++];
            }
        }
    }

    private static void shiftRows(byte[][] target, byte[] offsets)
    {
        int nCols = target[0].length;
        for (int row = 0;row < 4;row++)
        {
            byte[] rowBuff = new byte[offsets[row]];
            byte offset = offsets[row];
            System.arraycopy(target[row], 0, rowBuff, 0, offset);
            System.arraycopy(target[row], offset, target[row], 0, nCols - offset);
            System.arraycopy(rowBuff, 0, target[row], nCols - offset, offset);
        }
    }

    private static void mixColumns(byte[][] target)
    {
        byte[] t = new byte[4];
        int nCols = target[0].length;
        for (int col = 0;col < nCols;col++)
        {
            for (int row = 0;row < 4;row++)
            {
                t[row] = target[row][col];
            }
            for (int row = 0;row < 4;row++)
            {   
                /*
                state[r,c] = FFmul(0x02, t[r]) xor
                    FFmul(0x03, t[(r + 1) mod 4]) xor
                    t[(r + 2) mod 4] xor t[(r + 3) mod 4]
                */
                byte a = fieldMultiplication((byte) 2, t[row]);
                byte b = fieldMultiplication((byte) 3, t[(row + 1) % 4]);
                byte c = t[(row + 2) % 4];
                byte d = t[(row + 3) % 4];
                target[row][col] = (byte) (
                    a ^ b ^ c ^ d);

                if (col == 1 && (row == 1 || row == 2))
                {
                    int id = row;
                    System.out.println("FFmul(2, t[" + id + "] = "
                        + formatHex(t[id], '0') + ") = "
                        + formatHex(a, '0'));

                    id = (row + 1) % 4;
                    System.out.println("FFmul(3, t[(" + row + " + 1) % 4] = "
                        + "t[" + id + "] = "
                        + formatHex(t[id], '0') + ") = "
                        + formatHex(b, '0'));

                    id = (row + 2) % 4;
                    System.out.println("t[(" + row + " + 2) % 4] = "
                        + "t[" + id + "] = "
                        + formatHex(c, '0'));

                    id = (row + 3) % 4;
                    System.out.println("t[(" + row + " + 3) % 4] = "
                        + "t[" + id + "] = "
                        + formatHex(d, '0'));

                    System.out.println("=> " + formatHex((byte) (a ^ b ^ c ^ d), '0'));

                    System.out.println();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static byte lookupTable(byte[][] table, byte position)
    {
        int x = (position & 0xF0) >> 4;
        int y =  position & 0x0F;
        return table[x][y];
    }

    private static byte fieldMultiplication(byte a, byte b)
    {
        if (a != 0 && b != 0)
        {
            int t = lookupTable(logTable, a) + lookupTable(logTable, b);
            return lookupTable(powTable, (byte) (t % 0xFF));
        }
        else
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks to everyone who even got here! Any hint is welcome!

Comment: Are you sure you didn't make a typo when typing in constants or the hardcoded round subkeys?

Comment: +1 for your first question, as it's asked clearly.
However, your code is not really short... you should maybe use a debugger, and observe how the single instructions modify the result... this way it's easier to find errors.

Comment: I am pretty sure that there are no typos in the constants since i copie&paste'd them from the PDF file and used Regex to make them fit the Java-Syntax.

I'll try the debugger and post the results in a few mins.

Comment: Solved. See question for error cause and solution.

Comment: Please either post solution as an answer instead of an edit of the question, or delete the question if you don't think it will benefit others. You can accept your own answers, but you won't get any points for it (upvotes count though).

Comment: I agree with @owlstead and have rolled back  your last edit. Please post that as an answer, you may even get some up-votes.

Comment: Sorry for this but yesterday it told me that i need at least 50 reputation to answer my own questions.

Answer (score 0):

The error was in the method `fieldMultiplication`: `lookupTable(...) + lookupTable(...)` with either or both values greater than `0x7F` would not do an addition of the unsigned values but a more complex calculation with negative numbers (since bytes in Java are always signed). Thet let to a erronous result for `t` and resulted in the wrong lookup from `powTable`.

Changing the line

```
int t = lookupTable(logTable, a) + lookupTable(logTable, b);
```

into

```
int t = (lookupTable(logTable, a) & 0xFF) + (lookupTable(logTable, b) & 0xFF);
```

solved the problem. Thanks to Nik and Numbers for spending time and thoughts on this!